# Android timer not precise

Tags: java, android, timer

Ok, so, I'm a real beginner with both java and android programming.
I'm trying to make a Basketball application for friendly games. Right now I'm making a shotclock that counts from 24 to 0, plays a sound, and is reseted by a button.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ShotClock shotClock;
    private TextView shotClockTimer;
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    private Button shotClockReset;
    private final static int interval = 100;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        shotClockTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.shotClock);
        shotClockReset = (Button)findViewById(R.id.shotClockReset);
        shotClock = new ShotClock();
        shotClockReset.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                shotClock.shotClockReset();
            }

        });
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TimerMethod();
            }

        }, 0, interval);

    }

    private void TimerMethod() {
        this.runOnUiThread(Timer_Tick);
    }

    private Runnable Timer_Tick = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            shotClock.advanceClock();
            shotClockTimer.setText(String.format("%.1f",shotClock.getSeconds()));

        }
    };
}
```

The idea is that I have a timer that goes of every 0.1 seconds and update the clock accordingly. This works fine, the clock counts from 24-0 and resets properly. My issue is that it's not accurate - I tested it with 3 other timers, and it's always a bit slower: by the time other timers reach 0, this one is only at ~1-1.5 seconds left. What can I do to make it more accurate, besides changing the interval in a primitive way?
Please, be friendly since I'm new :)
Thanks for the help!

Comment: PS: in Java, by convention, only classes/interfaces start by upper-case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is because of internal scheduling,
the scheduler calls this method approximately every 0.1 seconds.
However, the system itself is accurate.
Use System.currentTimeMillis() to correct this error.

Android itself is no realtime application, but the system is the most accurate source you can get.

So programming precise stopwatches for sportsevents for example are no usecase in android ;)

Just loop and calculate the offset of miliseconds, if the offset is reached, call a method.

But think about inaccuracy here too. Calculate the offset always with the start-time (1*0.1 seconds, 2*0.1 seconds...), not with the last value, so minimize inaccuracy here.

Comment: That's the right way. You just have to store System.currentTimeMillis() at start and at each interval you calculate remaining time from that value. Then, also if you have not precise interval, the value you show is precise.

Comment: This worked. Still not 100% precise, but much better than before! Thanks a lot!

Comment: System.currentTimeMillis is milliseconds since epoch. Now think of this VERY BAD scenario. You had your phone totally discharged lying around for the weekend or you did remove the battery. Often when the phone/tab wakes up the clock is totally OFF.
When you have internet the clock should (and in most cases does) change to correct time after some seconds.

As you can see System.currentTimeMillis in this case also changes drastically when that occurs.

You can add a BroadcastReceiver that listens to Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED to detect that, but I doubt it will fire fast enough for 0.1sec

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with a sailing timer I made.
Use timer.scheduleAtFixedRate instead of timer.schedule.
This method can still cause tiny amounts of jitter to the scheduled ticks but the errors aren't cumulative, so the timer remains accurate over a long period.